# Datas overwriting problem with EntityType (same problem with ChoiceType) in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony

So here is my concern. I have a "Child" entity that contains $services and $users linked in ManyToMany.

The goal in my application is to be able to assign a child to a user of my service.
So, depending on the service I'm in, I won't have the same choice of users to assign.

In my ChildType, in my "users" field, I added a key ''query_builder'' that will retrieve only the users concerned.

My ChildType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Child;
use App\Entity\Service;
use App\Entity\Sexe;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\ServiceRepository;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var User $user */
    private $user;

    private $serviceRepository;

    private $authorization;


    public function __construct(Security $security, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorization, ServiceRepository $serviceRepository)
    {
        $this->user = $security->getUser();
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        $this->serviceRepository = $serviceRepository;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /** @var Service $service */
        $service = $this->user->getService();
        $builder
            ->add('nom', TextType::class)
            ->add('prenom', TextType::class)
            ->add('sexe', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Sexe::class,
            ])
            ->add('dateDeNaissance', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text'
            ])
            ->add('lieuDeNaissance', TextType::class)
            ->add('nationalite', TextType::class)
            ->add('dateElaborationPpe', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'single_text'
            ]);

        if ($this->authorization->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $builder->add('users', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                'label' => 'Affecter à un utilisateur',
                'query_builder' => function (UserRepository $userRepository) use ($service) {
                    return $userRepository->findByCurrentService($service);
                },
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ]);

            $builder->add('services', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Service::class,
                'label' => 'Affecter à un service',
                'choices' => $this->serviceRepository->findByDepartement($service->getDepartement()),
                'choice_attr' => function($key, $val, $index) use ($service) {
                    return([]);
                    return $key->getCategorie()->getId() === $service->getCategorie()->getId() ? 
                    ['disabled' => 'disabled'] : 
                    [];
                },
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Child::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The problem:

Let's assume that my Service #1 has several users from Service #1 to my child. When I assign in my Service #2 users from Service #2 to the child, I have my 2 new users from Service #2 in the database, but on the other hand, those from Service #1 have been deleted, which is not the desired behavior.

I've been looking for a topic for almost 2 hours, and I can't find an answer, so if it's a duplicate, really sorry.

edit method in my controller:

```
   /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="child_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Child $child): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted("edit", $child);

        $form = $this->createForm(ChildType::class, $child);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('child_show', ['id' => $child->getId()]);
        }

        return $this->render('child/edit.html.twig', [
            'child' => $child,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

User.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use App\Entity\Service;
use App\Traits\BlameableEntity;
use App\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 *
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    use BlameableEntity;
    use TimestampableEntity;
    
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $fullName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min=2, max=50)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastLogin;
    
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $secondToLastLogin;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $service;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Child", mappedBy="users")
     */
    private $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFullName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->fullName;
    }

    public function setFullName(string $fullName): self
    {
        $this->fullName = $fullName;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles or permissions granted to the user for security.
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;

        // guarantees that a user always has at least one role for security
        if (empty($roles)) {
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        }

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): void
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

     /**
     * Get the value of lastLogin
     *
     * @return  \DateTime
     */ 
    public function getLastLogin()
    {
        return $this->lastLogin;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of lastLogin
     *
     * @param  \DateTime  $lastLogin
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setLastLogin(\DateTime $lastLogin)
    {
        $this->lastLogin = $lastLogin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of secondToLastLogin
     *
     * @return  \DateTime
     */ 
    public function getSecondToLastLogin()
    {
        return $this->secondToLastLogin;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of secondToLastLogin
     *
     * @param  \DateTime  $secondToLastLogin
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setSecondToLastLogin(\DateTime $secondToLastLogin)
    {
        $this->secondToLastLogin = $secondToLastLogin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
        // if you had a plainPassword property, you'd nullify it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function serialize(): string
    {
        // add $this->salt too if you don't use Bcrypt or Argon2i
        return serialize([$this->id, $this->username, $this->password]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized): void
    {
        // add $this->salt too if you don't use Bcrypt or Argon2i
        [$this->id, $this->username, $this->password] = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of service
     */ 
    public function getService()
    {
        return $this->service;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of service
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setService($service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;

        return $this;
    }

    public function hasService(): bool
    {
        return !empty($this->getService());
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Child[]
     */
    public function getChildren(): Collection
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    public function addChild(Child $child): self
    {
        if (!$this->children->contains($child)) {
            $this->children[] = $child;
            $child->addUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeChild(Child $child): self
    {
        if ($this->children->removeElement($child)) {
            $child->removeUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getFullName();
    }
}
```

Service.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\ServiceRepository;
use App\Entity\Categorie;
use App\Entity\Departement;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ServiceRepository::class)
 */
class Service
{
    public const ASE = 'ASE';
    public const MDPH = 'MDPH';
    public const E_N = 'Éducation Nationale';

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var Departement
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Departement")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $departement;

    /**
     * @var Categorie
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorie")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $categorie;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="service")
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Child", mappedBy="services")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Element", mappedBy="services")
     */
    private $elements;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->elements = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of id
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of id
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setId(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of nom
     *
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of nom
     *
     * @param  string  $nom
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setNom(string $nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of departement
     *
     * @return  Departement
     */
    public function getDepartement()
    {
        return $this->departement;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of departement
     *
     * @param  Departement  $departement
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setDepartement(Departement $departement)
    {
        $this->departement = $departement;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of categorie
     *
     * @return  Categorie
     */
    public function getCategorie()
    {
        return $this->categorie;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of categorie
     *
     * @param  Categorie  $categorie
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setCategorie(Categorie $categorie)
    {
        $this->categorie = $categorie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Users[]
     */ 
    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
            $user->setService($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        if ($this->users->removeElement($user)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($user->getService() === $this) {
                $user->setService(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Children[]
     */ 
    public function getChildren(): Collection
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    public function addChild(Child $child): self
    {
        if (!$this->children->contains($child)) {
            $this->children[] = $child;
            $child->addService($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeChild(Child $child): self
    {
        if ($this->children->removeElement($child)) {
            $child->removeService($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Elements[]
     */ 
    public function getElements(): Collection
    {
        return $this->elements;
    }

    public function addElements(Element $element): self
    {
        if (!$this->children->contains($element)) {
            $this->elements[] = $element;
            $element->addService($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeElement(Element $element): self
    {
        if ($this->elements->removeElement($element)) {
            $element->removeService($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getNom();
    }
}
```

Child.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\Service;
use App\Entity\Sexe;
use App\Entity\User;
use DateTime;
use App\Repository\ChildRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use App\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use App\Traits\BlameableEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ChildRepository::class)
 */
class Child
{
    use BlameableEntity;
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $prenom;


    /**
     * @var Sexe
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sexe")
     */
    private $sexe;

    /**
     * @var date
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $dateDeNaissance;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $lieuDeNaissance;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $nationalite;

    /**
     * @var date
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateElaborationPpe;


    /**
     * @var Service[]|Collection
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $services;

    /**
     * @var User[]|Collection
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @var Element[]|Collection
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Element", mappedBy="child")
     */
    private $elements;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->elements = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of id
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of id
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setId(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNumDossier()
    {
        return str_pad($this->id, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of nom
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of nom
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setNom(string $nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of prenom
     */
    public function getPrenom()
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of prenom
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setPrenom(string $prenom)
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of sexe
     *
     * @return  Sexe
     */
    public function getSexe()
    {
        return $this->sexe;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of sexe
     *
     * @param  Sexe  $sexe
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setSexe(Sexe $sexe)
    {
        $this->sexe = $sexe;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of dateDeNaissance
     */
    public function getDateDeNaissance()
    {
        return $this->dateDeNaissance;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of dateDeNaissance
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setDateDeNaissance(datetime $dateDeNaissance)
    {
        $this->dateDeNaissance = $dateDeNaissance;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of lieuDeNaissance
     */
    public function getLieuDeNaissance()
    {
        return $this->lieuDeNaissance;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of lieuDeNaissance
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setLieuDeNaissance(string $lieuDeNaissance)
    {
        $this->lieuDeNaissance = $lieuDeNaissance;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of nationalite
     */
    public function getNationalite()
    {
        return $this->nationalite;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of nationalite
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setNationalite(string $nationalite)
    {
        $this->nationalite = $nationalite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of dateElaborationPpe
     */
    public function getDateElaborationPpe()
    {
        return $this->dateElaborationPpe;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of dateElaborationPpe
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setDateElaborationPpe(datetime $dateElaborationPpe)
    {
        $this->dateElaborationPpe = $dateElaborationPpe;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Service[]
     */
    public function getServices(): Collection
    {
        return $this->services;
    }

    public function addService(Service $service): self
    {
        if (!$this->services->contains($service)) {
            $this->services[] = $service;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeService(Service $service): self
    {
        $this->services->removeElement($service);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        $test = 'test';
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNbUsers()
    {
        return count($this->getUsers());
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Element[]
     */
    public function getElements(): Collection
    {
        return $this->elements;
    }

    public function addElement(Element $element): self
    {
        if (!$this->elements->contains($element)) {
            $this->elements[] = $element;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeElement(Element $element): self
    {
        $this->elements->removeElement($element);

        return $this;
    }


    public function isNotAssigned(): bool
    {
        return (!$this->getNbUsers());
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->getNom() . ' ' . $this->getPrenom();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: it's most likely your entity setup in combination with your form. show your entities and for brevity, remove everything except for the relations and their setters, getters, adders, removers.

Comment: Hello @Jakumi and thanks for your help. I edited my post to add the entities. On the other hand, I have a question about the addUser method of my User.php entity. Indeed, when I update my users, this method is not called (seen with the debugger xDebug).
For the moment I'm going in circles.
Thanks again anyway.

Comment: addUser not being called can be related to the getters returning collections and not having byReference set to false in the corresponding form fields (form may add straight to the collection in those cases)